# Multiple custome marker cluster in Folium

Tags: python, folium

```
map_toronto = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=12)

# add markers to map
for lat, lng, name, category in zip(df_toronto_cluster3['Venue_Latitude'], df_toronto_cluster3['Venue_Longitude'], df_toronto_cluster3['Venue'], df_toronto_cluster3['Venue_Category']):
    label = 'Name: {0}<br>Category: {1}'.format(name, category)
    iframe = folium.IFrame(html=label, width=300, height=100)
    popup = folium.Popup(iframe, parse_html=True)
    folium.CircleMarker([lat, lng],
                        radius=5,
                        popup=popup,
                        color='blue',
                        fill=True,
                        fill_color='blue',
                        fill_opacity=0.7,
                       ).add_to(map_toronto)

map_toronto
```

Code above is used in my project to make a cluster of marker on the map. This marker is colored blue.

As you can see, the above code take value in dataframe `df_toronto_cluster3` for labeling. I have many of this dataframe with different value and size.

What I wanna do is to plot all dataframe onto same map so that essentially create a different custom cluster marker.

Is there are way to do this or this is limitation of folium?

Comment: i don't think i understand your problem. why not just create a new marker for each dataframe?

Comment: repeat the for loop for different dataframe?